# Free java library for Gantt charts

Tags: java, animation, drag-and-drop, gantt-chart

I need in my program something like a Gantt chart, with multiple tasks per line.

One requirement is that the tasks can be rearranged, by drag and drop and ideally it also supports animation.

Can someone recommend from experience a free Java library which would make my life easier? It doesn't need to be specifically designed for creating Gantt charts, but it should be easily used to implement them.

I've looked into JFreeChart but it doesn't rise up to the task.

Comment: Have you [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+gantt+is%3Aquestion) before asking?

Comment: @assylias Yes, and I didn't find anything addressing a java implementation and the features I need.

Comment: @PoatoSong I suggest you clicked on the link in my previous comment - there are at least 3 or 4 questions that address the same question.

Comment: Here is the project you need http://www.lowcoupling.com/mdpm it is an open source eclipse extension for project management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking into the exact same thing, and unfortunately I never found anything better than JFreeChart... :( It's a big downside that you cannot drag and rearrange the tasks.

There are plenty other options, but they all have hefty licensing fees.

[Nebula GANTT Chart Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/ganttchart/ganttchart.php) could be useful if you're developing a program based on the eclipse platform. 
But we're developing on the netbeans platform, and I think it would be a hassle to port it..

Some other opions I looked into;

[SwiftGantt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftgantt/), it fell on that it seemed to be outdated, and not very well used.

These all fell on that the license was too expensive. We wanted open source...

[JavaGantt](http://www.beesoft.eu/products/jgantt/overview.php)

[FlexGantt](http://www.dlsc.com/index.php/flexgantt)

[JIDE Gantt Chart](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/gantt.htm)

[VarChat JGantt 3.0](http://www.netronic.com/products/varchart-jgantt/overview.html)

Comment: my I invite you to try our open source project based on Nebula? see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFFt2gyQW0s and http://www.lowcoupling.com/mdpm